# Pythonic way to find index of certain char in a circular manner

Tags: python

Let's say I have a string like:

```
'abcdefgha'
```

I'd like to find the index of the next character `a` after the index 2 (in a circular manner). Meaning it should find index 7 in this case (via `mystr.index('a', 2)`); however, in this case:

```
'abcdefgh'
```

it should return index 0. Is there any such built-in function?

Comment: What about something like  `mystr[2:].index('a') + 2`?

Comment: What is adding `2` to a `ValueError` supposed to do for the second case @shadowtalker ?

Comment: @shadowtalker That's just a bad version of what they already showed.

Comment: Does "circular" mean "loops around"?

Comment: I didn't see the "circular" part, my mistake.

Comment: Can you explain why the expected result is 7 for your first example?

Comment: Yes, I would expect `8` in that case (or `6`, if you start counting from index `2`).

Comment: @shadowtalker Even without that part, it's just worse than their `mystr.index('a', 2)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a builtin for this, but you can easily write a function:

```
def index_circular(s: str, sub: str, n: int) -> int:
    try:
        # Search starting from n
        return s.index(sub, n)
    except ValueError:
        # Wrap around and search from the start, until n
        return s.index(sub, 0, n+len(sub)-1)
```

In use:

```
>>> n = 2
>>> c = 'a'
>>> index_circular('abcdefgha', c, n)
8
>>> index_circular('abcdefgh', c, n)
0
>>> index_circular('bcdefgh', c, n)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
ValueError: substring not found
```

(Note that `'a'` actually occurs at index 8, not 7, in the first case.)

**Note**: In the second `s.index` call, I'm setting the `end` parameter in order to avoid searching parts of the string that have already been searched. This is a bit of a premature optimization, but it's also a bit of a clarification about exactly which parts of the string are being searched in each step. The `+len(sub)-1` is to allow for multi-character `sub` that spans index `n`, like:

```
>>> index_circular('abc', 'ab', 1)
0
```

Comment: Is this typical Python style? For a function to throw an exception instead of returning an error (perhaps only returning positive indices upon success and `-1` when it can't find it)?

Comment: @user129393192 You yourself mentioned index() instead of find(), suggesting you prefer an exception.

Comment: I think the simple `s.index(sub)` works @wjandrea

Comment: @user129393192 I edited to clarify why I'm setting the `end` parameter.

Comment: @user129393192 Yes, this is typical. One way to put it is, ["if your method can't do what its name says it does, throw."](/a/1153149/4518341) It's also related to [EAFP](//docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-EAFP).

Comment: The multi-char support seems broken/misleading, as it fails on `index_circular('abc', 'ca', 1)`.

Comment: @KellyBundy It only looks for substrings that exist in the original string. The question is only about single characters so I didn't bother thinking too hard about it.

Answer (score 3):

Python has no built-in function for this circular index lookup, so you'll need to implement one yourself.

#### Custom implementation

One way to do circular lookup is to leverage the `str.index` combined with a modular approach to "wrap around" the string.

Here's the complete example.

```py
def circular_index(s, char, start):
    try:
        # Try finding the character after the start index.
        return s.index(char, start)
    except ValueError:
        # If not found, try finding from the beginning
        # This will raise ValueError if not found again
        return s.index(char)

# Test
s1 = 'abcdefgha'
s2 = 'abcdefgh'

print(circular_index(s1, 'a', 2))  # prints 8
print(circular_index(s2, 'a', 2))  # prints 0
```

Comment: What's the point of a default value of `0` for `start`? In that case if the substring isn't found, you'll end up doing `s.index` twice. The caller should just use `s.index` in the first place in that case, no?

Comment: @wjandrea yeah, you're right, I'll edit this out

Comment: @wjandrea I think even better would be (for both of you) to handle that case within the new function.

Comment: @LoverofStructure If I were writing for a library then I might, but for this question, it's not super relevant. Like, I'd be willing to assume the caller is setting `start != 0` otherwise they'd just use `str.index` in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

You can try `find()` or `rfind()`:

```
def cir_idx(string, sub, n):
    res = string.find(sub, n)
    if res == -1:
        res = string.find(sub)
    return res

print(cir_idx('abcdefgh', 'a', 2)) # 0
print(cir_idx('abcdefgha', 'a', 2)) # 8
print(cir_idx('abcdefghaa', 'a', 2)) # 8
print(cir_idx('aabcdefgh', 'a', 2)) # 0
print(cir_idx('aaabcdefgh', 'a', 2)) # 2
print(cir_idx('bcdefgh', 'a', 2)) # -1
```

Comment: This would be correct, except when the highest-indexed occurrence isn't the next occurence after the index I want to specify.

Comment: Looks good, and I've just upvoted. @user129393192 I think your comment above can be deleted now.